# Using dict() function to create a dictionary object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

I am able to create the `dictionary` object as follows:

```
a = dict(name='John', country='Norway')
```

The gives an output as: `{'name': 'John', 'country': 'Norway'}`

However, the following statement is throwing an error:

```
dict([(name, 'John'), (country, 'Norway')])
```

> Error:

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

In both syntax, I am using `name` and `country` without quotes but only the second syntax is throwing an error.

The second syntax is working correctly with following code:

```
a = dict([(1, 'John'), (2, 'Norway')])
```

Output: `{1: 'John', 2: 'Norway'}`

Comment: Former `name` is used as a name of an argument (called keyword arguments), just like you would use in any function. Later is used as an element of a `tuple`, and thus it is considered to be a variable.

Comment: In the first, you're treating `name` and `country` as keyword arguments to the `dict()` function. If you've worked with keyword arguments in Python before, you'll realize that they are actually just dictionaries. So what you're actually doing is passing a dictionary to the dictionary "constructor". The second doesn't work because you're just trying to pass tuples with undefined variables in them.

Comment: The last example works because `1` and `2` are valid data types (they are of type int) whereas `name` isn't. Here you need a string as data type, so use `'name'` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...

For the first example, this is how it's done:

```
def dummydict(**kwargs):
    return kwargs
```

---

```
>>> dummydict(a=1, b=2, c=4)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
>>>
```

As you can see, `**kwargs` unpacks the keyword arguments into a dictionary, that's why it works.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html#usage-of-kwargs):

> **kwargs allows you to pass **keyworded** variable length of arguments to a function. You should use **kwargs if you want to handle **named arguments** in a function.

For why the second example doesn't work, it is because it gets treated as a variable name, the second one isn't named arguments, it's only tuples in a list, you would have to do:

```
dict([('name', 'John'), ('country', 'Norway')])
```

Comment: can you please provide some explanation on why `a = dict([(1, 'John'), (2, 'Norway')])` is working?

Comment: @meallhour It's because `1` is an integer, which is a literal that is not a variable, but `name` is not a string. It's the same logic as `'name'`.